# Angular ViewChild valueChange handler stops firing after component is hidden and reshown by *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using `combineLatest` to get some information about parts (by `partId`) that are stocked at different warehouses (by `stockLocationId`) based on user changes to either the location or the part number.

This works great until the form that contains these fields (AKA `ViewChild` components) is hidden via `*ngIf`.  Does `*ngIf==false` on the parent container for these components result in the components being recreated - and if so, is there a reasonable way to rebind the `valueChange` handlers?

Here is an excerpt of `component.ts` with my dynamic components from `component.html` followed by my `combineLatest` method. The subscriber executes fine until I toggle the view to the cart `div` from the line item details `div` but after going back to edit an item from my cart, which re-shows these fields, the subscriber that looks up the stock information like quantity is no longer triggering on change of the part or location fields.

```
  @ViewChild('fldPart', { static: false }) fldPart: FieldComponent;
  @ViewChild('fldStockLocation', { static: false }) fldStockLocation: FieldComponent;
```

...

```
  combineLatest(
    partIdField.valueChange.pipe(startWith(this.currentPartRequest.partId)),
    locationIdField.valueChange.pipe(startWith(this.currentPartRequest.partRequestLocationId)),
    (partId, stockLocationId) => { return { valid: partIdField.isValid && locationIdField.isValid, partId: <string>partId, stockLocationId: <string>stockLocationId }; }
  ).pipe(
    debounceTime(250),
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
  ).subscribe(({ valid, partId, stockLocationId }) =>
  {
    // do stuff.. 
    // works fine at first, but stops working after components hidden and reshown
    console.log("value for partId or stockLocationId changed");
  });
```

Is there a better way than to rebind the `valueChange` handler whenever these components' container is toggled to show/hide? I may not always know when that will happen (especially in the general sense; i.e.: for other pages I am working on). Is there a way to force these ViewChild references to stay the same even when the components they refer to are being hidden with `*ngIf` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*ngIf` toggle destroys and re-creates the component

Use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` if you want to conditionally hide the component

Answer (score 1):

`*ngIf` removes the element from the Dom and destroys the component instance (life cycle hook `ngOnDestroy` is called.).

You either need to resubscribe to the new `valueChanges' or use other means to hide your element. Like using css 'display: none', which would only hide the element but would not remove the element from the Dom.